# Log4j logs not formed on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, log4j, websphere-traditional

I am trying to view log4j files for the WARs that I deployed on Websphere. My Websphere is in a docker container with Ubuntu base image. I gave the -Dlogs-path=/home/agilisserver in my JVM arguments on the Admin console. But I cannot see the logs in the specified location. In fact, the folder agilisserver itself is not getting created in /home directory.
Somehow I see the logs on a Windows system, but not on Linux (Ubuntu). Please help.

Comment: Websphere is running under `root` user, `agilisserver` user or what?

Comment: solved. thank you :)

Comment: then you can post the solution, maybe it would be useful for somebody

Comment: I added 'USER root' in my Dockerfile and rebuilt the image :)